# Is there a way to inherit this javascript pattern?

Tags: javascript, oop

I have this javascript pattern and I'd like to do inheritance. Can someone tell me how to do it?

```
var NameSpace = { App: {} };
NameSpace.App.Main = (function($) {
 var Main = function(options) {
  var _private;

  _private = function() {
   console.log('this is a private function');
  };

  return {
   public: function() {
    console.log('this is the public function');
   }
  };
 };

 return function(options) {
  return new Main(options);
 };
})(jQuery);
```

What I'd like to have is something that inherits the functions from the object like

```
var obj = new NameSpace.App.NewMain();
obj.public();
```

Thanks for any advice
{Jim}

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `prototype` of a function object in order to do proper inheritance.

```
function Child(){ ... }
Child.prototype = new NameSpace.App.NewMain();

var inst = new Child();
inst.public();
```